# pytest mark parametrize a fixture

Tags: python, testing, pytest, tdd, fixtures

I want to test a function `get_xyz(a, b, foo)`, where foo is a class. A `foo_fixture` is defined in a conftest.py like so:

```
@pytest.fixture()
def foo_fixture():
    return Foo()
```

The fixture simply returns a new instance of a class Foo. How would I parametrize this foo_fixture as an argument to `test_get_xyz`? I have tried the below code but it doesn't work, also have read about using indirect=True in the parametrize decorator but also couldn't get that to work properly...

```
@pytest.mark.parametrize("a,b,foo_fixture",
                         [1, 2, pytest.lazy_fixture('foo_fixture')]
                        )
def test_get_xyz(a, b, foo_fixture):
    get_xyz(a, b, foo_fixture)
```

Comment: try using `yield Foo()` instead of `return Foo()`

Comment: why would that help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is implementation with indirect parametrize:

```
import pytest


class Foo:
    pass


@pytest.fixture
def foo_fixture():
    return Foo()


@pytest.mark.parametrize(
    "a, b, foo_fixture",
    [
        (1, 2, None),
        (3, 4, None),
        (5, 6, None),
    ],
    indirect=["foo_fixture"]
)
def test_get_xyz(a, b, foo_fixture):
    print("\n", a, b, foo_fixture)
```

Output is:

```
PASSED                          [ 33%]
 1 2 <test_indirect.Foo object at 0x000002318A4084C0>
PASSED                          [ 66%]
 3 4 <test_indirect.Foo object at 0x000002318A408610>
PASSED                          [100%]
 5 6 <test_indirect.Foo object at 0x000002318A4086A0>
```

As you can see Foo is different instance in each test.

Read more about [indirect parametrize](https://docs.pytest.org/en/7.1.x/example/parametrize.html#indirect-parametrization).

Basically you just specify which of your parameters are fixtures and pass any value for it (`None` for example).

If you need to change something in fixture based on passed parameters then you will need to pass some value instead of `None` and grab it inside `foo_fixture` using `request` fixture like this:

```
@pytest.fixture
def foo_fixture(request):
    return Foo(request.param)
```